# Google Wi-Fi Assistant VPN

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow

I have a Google Nexus 5, running 6.0.1.

I'm trying to figure out how to reconnect to the network I'm on through the Google Wi-Fi Assistant VPN.

Today is the first time I ever used it, because I got a notification for it. I went through the steps to turn it on and it worked great. I then got curious, wondering if I could get around the WebSense blocks (security crap) at work by using the Wi-Fi Assistant VPN.

To do this I had to turn the Wi-Fi Assistant VPN off for a moment. After I tested to see that using the VPN does indeed allow me to get around the security block, I can't seem to get it to use the VPN again.

I go into `Settings -> Google -> Networking -> Enable Wi-Fi Assistant`, but I never get the question in the notification area asking if I wanted to allow Wi-Fi assistant to connect through the VPN.

So now I'm connected to my network like normal, but it's missing the key icon and it does not say `Connected, via Wi-Fi assistant`.

Is there a way I can manually do this?

Update: The Google VPN was not working because the network is password protected, rather than an open network. I'm not sure what caused the VPN to connect when I initially enabled it. The answer below describes how to reconnect to an open network to start using the Google VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the VPN, the [documentation](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6327199?hl=en) suggests

> If you'd already connected to the network manually, you can "forget" the network. Wi-Fi assistant will then re-connect automatically.

because

> Wi-Fi assistant doesn't connect to networks to which you've already connected manually.

Comment: I forgot I had this question up. I've assumed that it isn't working because the Wi-Fi network is not open. I tried to forget the network and reconnect at the time, but it didn't work. I don't know why it connected with the VPN in the first place. It must have been a glitch or something. Assuming the network is open, your method would work.